# Influencing the style of a focused button in GTK

Tags: button, user-interface, gtk, focus

I'm using a lot of buttons (like a dial pad) in my application and the user can choose to click any button with the mouse or use the cursor arrow keys to place the focus on the wanted button (and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to push the button).  But unfortunately the focus style of the buttons is not very obvious.  It merely is a thin red line the button is framed with.

Since I've got a lot of buttons and my buttons also are rather large (this is an application for children), this "unobtrusive" focus marker is not of my taste.  I would like to have something more obvious, maybe the thin red line should be thicker, or the background of the button (displaying text or an icon) should change.  Any other idea on how to make this more of a jump-in-the-eye kind would be appreciated.

Example code (in Python, but solutions in other languages using GTK should do as well, so I deliberately **don't** tag this question as *Python*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

def init():
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    table = gtk.Table(2, 1)
    button1 = gtk.Button("Hello")
    button2 = gtk.Button("World")
    table.attach(button1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
    table.attach(button2, 1, 2, 0, 1)
    window.add(table)
    button1.show()
    button2.show()
    table.show()
    window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    gtk.main()
```

Also I'd like to know if I need to do whatever is necessary to each and every button?  Or is there something general to influence all optical focus marks?

Answer (score 0):

You can influence the style of all or part of your application using [`Gtk.CssProvider`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html):

```
provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
provider.load_from_data('''
    GtkButton {
        -GtkWidget-focus-line-width: 3px;
    }
''')
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), provider,
    Gtk.STYLE_CONTEXT_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

Comment: Any idea what I will have to import in Python (pygtk) in order to have that `Gtk` you are referring to?  I normally only import `gtk`, and that does provide neither `CssProvider` nor `StyleContext`, nor STYLE_CONTEXT_PRIORITY_APPLICATION`.  I'm using `pygtk` 2.24.10 btw, in case that is important.

Comment: Aha, I failed to notice you were using the old `pygtk`. You may be able to do something with [`GtkRcStyle`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Resource-Files.html) but honestly I don't think you can change the focus rectangles at all in GTK 2.

Comment: Anything else which makes the focus more obvious would suit me fine as well.  I now have a hacky change of the background when getting and losing focus; it works and highlights the focused button in a pale green, but I think it could be done better.

Comment: You could listen to the focus change events and set a flag if the button is focused; then in the button's expose-event handler draw an extra indicator on the button.